# How I enable parent JFrame after close child?

Tags: java, swing

I have a frame, on this frame I have a Menu with About MenuItem. When we select it the program opens a new `JPanel` with texts and with OK button and the enabled status of parent panel is set to false.

And now comes a problem. When we click on OK, then I want to close this About panel, and I want to turn to parent panel, and I want to enable it!

Please tell me, how?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Without further details, I would suggest a `CardLayout` might be a good place to start, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: Why is the frame disabled? Generally you would use a `modal JDialog` for an "About window". The modal dialog will prevent you from clicking on the frame and the frame will receive control when the dialog is closed.

Comment: Is it really a JPanel or a JDialog that opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `WindowListener` that reacts to the closing event of the about-dialog. You can add this in your frame or in the constructor of your dialog, just set the variables accordingly.

```
myDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        parentFrame.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

If you really only have a switching `JPanel`, use a `ButtonListener`.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when button is pressed
        frame.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, using a modal `JDialog` would be a more elegant way of solving the problem of disabling a parent frame while a dialog is active. [Here is a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simply a [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) (particularly the [showMessageDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) method)? You can specify there an `Object` (for example a `JPanel`) which will be presented in a modal dialog. Take a look at this sample code I've written for you (I've used a `JButton`, but it will be the same for `JMenuItem`):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AboutDialogDemo extends JFrame {

    private final JButton btnAbout = new JButton("About...");

    public AboutDialogDemo() {
        final JFrame thisFrame = this;
        btnAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thisFrame, new AboutPanel());
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(btnAbout, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AboutDialogDemo frame = new AboutDialogDemo();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class AboutPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JLabel lblAbout = new JLabel("Sample about text");

    public AboutPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(lblAbout, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

I hope you'll find it useful

Comment: This code is okey, bu wanna know what is it about the OK button on the AboutPanel? when you click the OK button on the about Me panel, how that frame closed itself?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks What do you mean?